# ¿How can a phone without power access a google account?

Tags: google-account

When checking the recently used devices on my google account, an old phone of mine that has been without battery for months appeared as a device that "accessed yesterday". Nobody else had access to where i had the phone and I didn't even touch it.
How can this be possible?